# Is TM4C123 similar to Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm currently studying embedded systems on eDx.
https://courses.edx.org/courses/UTAustinX/UT.6.01x/1T2014/info (must login to see)
http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~valvano/edX/index.html (don't need to login)
and I found out that TM4C123 is quite similar to Arduino.
but I haven't worked TM4C123 yet.(I ordered it and I'm waiting for it)
 I don't know much about it.
and it's not that popular as Arduino I guess.
so If anyone has used Tm4C123, please give me some information compared to Arduino.

Comment: This link does not show anything about this course or requires registration, this is not acceptable. Rather try to copy part of the course description to your question so that we know what it is about.

Comment: @jfpoilpret I'm sorry. I've just added the link. thanks :)

Comment: It's a micro controller, just like an Arduino. But it's more powerful than an Arduino. 32-bit instead of 8-bit architecture, faster clock-speed, more flash memory, more s-ram, usb-support. You just don't get the ton's of libraries and tutorials that are available for arduino.

Comment: @Gerben: Seen the Due yet?

Comment: Arduino'like IDE for Launchpad http://energia.nu/

Answer (score 3):

The [Tiva C LaunchPad](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-tm4c123gxl) is comparable to the Arduino Due in power and capabilities, but is incompatible with the stock Arduino ecosystem. It uses "[BoosterPacks](https://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/boosterpacks.html)" rather than [Shields](http://shieldlist.org/), and [Code Composer Studio](http://www.ti.com/tool/ccstudio) (or other [some non-gratis] tools) instead of the Arduino IDE and libraries.

The [Energia IDE](http://energia.nu/) is a port of the Arduino IDE and significantly simplifies configuration and programming Tiva C launchpads.

Beware of odd quirks with the Tiva C Launchpad board, such as the [0-ohm shunts that must be removed](http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/tiva_arm/f/908/t/236248) if you want all pins to be completely independent.

Comment: But if you're looking to jump from an AVR-based Arduino then I recommend the MSP430-based LaunchPads instead.

Comment: Actually, as the Tiva C has an ARM Cortex-M4 CPU it is likely that free toolchains can be used and an Arduino port seems possible.  But yes, it is quite different hardware and *from the manufacturer* a quite different environment.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I have completed the edX course, and the TM4C123 is significantly different to the Arduino from a programming perspective. Each family of microcontrollers have (on the surface) a fair amount in common - GPIO pins, an ADC or two, timers etc. However the way these work internally are very different - different registers, different process for using them, different gotchas to look out for, etc. If you're looking at tackling a new MCU family, be prepared to effectively learn a new "language".

Incidentally, the Launchpads from Texas Instruments have a processing-based language similar to the Arduino - called Energia - which should work on your TM4C123.

Enjoy the course, I did.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
I have a question.
Do you think TM4C123 will be more popular or it's just for embedded students or hobbyists??

Comment: @StarbuckSb: With all due respect to TI, I honestly don't think they can make something that can displace the Arduino any time soon. Which is fine, they don't have to; their products are excellent regardless.